# Html editor not work asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have one task in that i have to add html editor for that i code like this.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

it's work fine.

now i add some url routing code in "Global.asax" like this..

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup

    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);


}
public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "{Name}",
        "~/Membersite.aspx");
}
```

and than run application at that time my html editor is not display only simple textbox (id=TextBox1) is display.
any help is please it good for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add ignore route for .axd files to your route method:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");//add this line 

    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "{Name}",
        "~/Membersite.aspx");
}
```

Tell the routing API to not route the files with "axd" extension (the files generated by the scriptmanager)